# Modules are not recognized after install

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have downloaded selenium module and installed it using `python setup.py install`. When i open up Pycharm and try to `import Selenium` it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/mali03/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/exe.py", line 1, in 
<module> from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named selenium'
```

Is it because of the interpreter? Where did python install the module and how do i access it?

Comment: DO you have python 2.7 and 3 installed ?  what is the path variable pointing to ?

Comment: Make sure PyCharm is pointed to the correct python directory.  It is no uncommon for pycharm to create a virtual environment and bypass the root python config.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of Pycharm doesn't know where to find out selenium, or which python interpreter you are using.
Please select correct Python version.
You can found them in Settings | Project Interpreter > Wheel - More > Show Paths for the selected interpreter"